# Mixing several files column by column in bash

Tags: bash, text, merge, conditional-statements, concatenation

I would like to merge four `.txt` files into in a unique file. However, the idea is not a simple concatenation, but otherwise an 'interlacement' between the input files where the `file1` will be the first three columns and `files 2-4` must be pasted column by column in a subsequent order. Thus we have:

`file1`:

```
file1 <- '  AX-1   1    125    
            AX-2   2    456
            AX-3   3    3445'
file1 <- read.table(text=file1, header=F)
write.table(file1, "file1.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

`file2`:

```
file2 <- '  AX-1   AA  AB  AA    
            AX-2   AA  AA  AB
            AX-3   BB  NA  AB'
file2 <- read.table(text=file2, header=F)
write.table(file2, "file2.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

`file3`:

```
file3 <- '  AX-1   0.20  -0.89  0.005    
            AX-2   0  -0.56  -0.003
            AX-3   1.2  0.002  0.005'
file3 <- read.table(text=file3, header=F)
write.table(file3, "file3.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

`file4`:

```
file4 <- '  AX-1   1  0  0.56    
            AX-2   0  0.56  0
            AX-3   1  0  0.55'
file4 <- read.table(text=file34, header=F)
write.table(file4, "file4.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

Where my expected `out` file could be something like:

```
out <- 'AX-1   1    125  AA  0.2  1 AB -0.89 0 AA 0.005 0.56
        AX-2   2    456  AA  0   0 AA -0.56 0.56 AB -0.003 0
        AX-3   3    3445  BB  1.2  1 NA  0.002 0 AA 0.005 0.55'
out <- read.table(text=out, header=F)
write.table(out, "out.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

Thus, in the `out`: the column `1-3` are the `file1`, the columns `4,7 and 10` came from `file2`, the columns `5,8 and 11` came from `file3` and the columns `6,9 and 12` came from `file4`.

I have an idea how to do it in `R`, but my original files are too large and it will take a lot of time. I would be grateful if someone has an idea how to perform it directly in bash.

Comment: Perhaps explain what the code does, for those of us who know Bash but not R,

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$ join a1 a2 | join - a3 | join - a4 | awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $7, $10, $5, $8, $11, $6, $9, $12}'
AX-1 1 125 AA 0.20 1 AB -0.89 0 AA 0.005 0.56
AX-2 2 456 AA 0 0 AA -0.56 0.56 AB -0.003 0
AX-3 3 3445 BB 1.2 1 NA 0.002 0 AB 0.005 0.55
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 paste file1 file2 file3 file4 | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $5 " " $9 " " $13 " " $6 " " $10 " " $14 " " $7 " " $11 " " $15 }'
```

this works if your files have ordered rows, join suggested by Mauro is better choice.